# Что значит "'webkitOfflineAudioContext' is deprecated. Please use 'OfflineAudioContext' instead."

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что значит "'webkitOfflineAudioContext' is deprecated. Please use 'OfflineAudioContext' instead."

Comment: Вам предлагаю использовать функцию OfflineAudioContext вместо устаревшей webkitOfflineAudioContext.

Answer (score 2):

Написано же, используйте без префикса `OfflineAudioContext`